# pip package to install from url -- can it be encrypted?

Tags: python, pip

We have our own internal tool kit that we are packaging into a pip package.

Is there a way we can encrypt the packate itself to protect its contents? (Not the sources so much as some of the config info that is included in a couple of the sources.)

Ideally, we would run something like:

```
pip install http://www.oursite.com/testpackage/testingkit.tar.gz -decrypt=(crypto key)
```

Comment: @cel PIP could specify that it handles a specific crypto scheme, or the packaging mechanism itself would do a specific crypto, or there would be addl params to either specify crypto method or what cmd to run to decrypt.

Comment: Sorry, typed before thinking. :P

Comment: @cel No worries. The other reason to support crypto in pip is that your method requires scripting (to download, then run pip). Pip has such great native "download and update/install" functionality, it is a shame to have to "start over."